# Overloading == and !=, but program only use the former

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, inline

My code look like this

```
template <typename T>
class FArray
{
/* ... */
    inline bool operator == (const FArray& b) const
    {
        return std::equal(begin(),end(),b.begin());
    }
    inline bool operator != (const FArray& b) const
    {
        return !(*this == b);
    }
};
```

Then I have some unit tests, and I'm testing equality and inequality

```
FArray<double> a, b, c;
/* ... */
ASSERT_TRUE(a == b)
ASSERT_TRUE(a != c)
```

The second assert doesn't use the overloaded operator `!=`, it uses only `==` and I think returns its negation (I added a breakpoint in the overloaded function, my program doesn't go through it). But if I don't overload one or the other, I can't compile. Is it standard behavior? I couldn't find any related info about this online.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017 15.5.6, with Visual C++ 2017 - 00369-60000-00001-AA639.

Comment: On an unrelated note, your `operator==` function should probably compare the sizes of your "array" and that of the argument. If `b` is smaller than the "array" of `this` then you will go beyond `b.end()` and that might lead to *undefined behavior*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It uses `operator==` because it is invoked in `operator!=`.

It uses *only* `operator==` because `operator!=` might be [inlined](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline),

> instead of executing the function call CPU instruction to transfer control to the function body, a copy of the function body is executed without generating the call.

Then you won't see the invocation if it's the case.

It's also worth noting that the function is inlined or not depends on the compiler; it's not guaranteed.

> Since this meaning of the keyword `inline` is non-binding, compilers are free to use inline substitution for any function that's not marked inline, and are free to generate function calls to any function marked inline.

Comment: Does it happen in debug mode as well?

Comment: @Yola It's not guaranteed and depended on the compiler.